# Embedding YouTube videos?

Tags: html, youtube, embed

I have been looking for a way of embedding youtube videos into my site. The website is made of html and the youtube videos should auto-update as I would like to display all the videos on the current account? I know theres ways of embedding one video or playlists but Im not quite sure how to go about embedding everything on a users channel? Any Tips?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following as the `src` of an `iframe`:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=user_uploads&list=*USERNAME*
```

For example:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" width="640" height="360"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=user_uploads&list=apple"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get info on the parammeters of the player on this link: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Manual_IFrame_Embeds

Scroll a little and you will see the url for user videos.